Why no location settings showing up in my simulator app settings?
//pubspec.yaml 
permission_handler: ^11.3.1
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHome()));

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  PermissionStatus _status = PermissionStatus.denied; // Start with denied state
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkPermissionStatus();
  }

  Future<void> _checkPermissionStatus() async {
    final status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;
    _updateStatus(status);
  }

  void _updateStatus(PermissionStatus status) {
    if (status != _status) {
      setState(() {
        _status = status;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _requestPermission() async {
    final status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
    _updateStatus(status);

    if (status.isDenied) {
      _showDialog('Permission Denied', 'Location permission is denied.');
    } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      _showDialog(
        'Permission Permanently Denied',
        'Please enable location permission in settings.',
        showSettings: true,
      );
    }
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Permission Handler Example'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Location Permission Status: $_status'),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _requestPermission,
                child: Text('Request Location Permission'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I tried flutter clean then flutter build but still there is no settings about location in my
iOS simulator ?
my dependencies seems okey my plist seems okey but still nothing ...
details about the questions ..........................................................................
...........
......
.
.
.
..
.

Are you see the dialog open up to ask the permission? What is the OS version on the simulator you are using?

my os version is 17.3

i see no dialog but it navigates me my app settings and where is no location permission

This question is similar to: Flutter: Location permission: when in use or always. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
